# Could not dump table "data" because of following StandardError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

My Rails app has a remote database, where I create and store tables independently of the app and it's "modelless", where I don't want or need a model or ORM for those tables. To access the data I use a simple `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)`command.

My `schema.rb` has a lot of this commented messages:

```
# Could not dump table "geographic_data" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'geometry(MultiLineString,4326)' for column 'geom'
```

My problem/doubt:

If I install the ActiveRecord PostGIS Adapter, will it purge all the data that I already have in these non-model tables? Is that a possible scenario?

Comment: Happens if you accidentally get the column name and type the wrong way around, e.g. `add_column :people, :string, :first_name`, instead of `add_column :people, :first_name, :string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory it should not because you will only run `rake db:schema:dump` to get all the schema, but to be on the safe side - better test it on a staging/development environment.

If you do not need that adapter for anything else than schema dumps, or it does not cover it fully (for example should you have some triggers/stored functions etc.) - you can switch to using a sql-format rails schema in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```